# Main effects of 2-way ANOVA - same as 1-way ANOVA on each main effect?

Tags: anova

I'm working on a 2-way ANOVA analysis with a 2x2 design - two main effects with 2 levels each.  In running the analysis, I obviously get the interaction as well as each main effect.

Are the results (p and F values) for the main effects the same as if I had simply run a standard ANOVA on each of the main effects independently?  That is my interpretation, but when I actually do the test, I get different p and F values.

Comment: Is it a balanced design?

Comment: yes.  8 samples per group, all independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a balanced two-way design (all cells equally frequent), the two-way ANOVA without interaction will basically return the same p values for the main effects as the two one-way ANOVAs. (Slightly different degrees of freedom but the hypotheses are the same.)

In the model with interaction, the same is true only if you use *orthogonal contrasts* (e.g. effect coding aka sum contrasts, or Helmert contrasts). If you use treatment contrasts (aka dummy coding), then your "main" effects have a completely different meaning than in the one-way ANOVAs (or the two-way ANOVA without interaction) and thus their tests are usually meaningless.

In short: In the model with interaction, just look at the interaction term. If you are interested in main effects, then run the model without interaction or use proper contrasts.

Comment: could you explain more in detail about the actual difference in meaning between main effects in two-way model with interaction and one-way model when using treatment contrasts?